# Can I bring 50 ml vitamin D3 in carry-on luggage on a flight from Germany to Austria?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, hand-luggage

It is a pipette bottle with 15,000,000 IU (375 mg) vitamin D3 in 50 ml orange/mandarin/olive oil:

https://www.vitabay.net/vitamin-d3-liquid-10.000-ie-depot-vegane-tropfen-nur-eine-portion/10-tage-1856?number=VO1677

This is a toxic amount. The recommended dosage is 1 drop every 10 days (10 g paracetamol are toxic, too, btw.)

I have only carry-on luggage, no check in luggage (actually a friend who wants to bring me the bottle.)

Would it help if we freeze the oil, so it's no longer a liquid?

Comment: Where does it say I cannot do that in Germany? "They" didn't ask me that in Austria or Greece.  Where can I buy 15,000,000 IU vitamin D for 24.99 EUR in Austria?

Comment: hi new user, I see what you mean - it's just something "you're buying, to give to them".  i thought you meant someone "asked you to carry it on their behalf".  Cheers!

Comment: Note that you can very easily find that product at the same or lower price in Austria - just FYI.  You can even buy it on Amazon.at !!   :O   https://www.amazon.de/Vitamin-D3-Liquid-10-000-Depot/dp/B0759VKQFM/

Comment: Schnäppchen .. 6 zum preis 5 ?? amazon.at!  :)

Comment: Zuerst ist der Preis 24.99 EUR, im Warenkorb auch, aber beim Bezahlformular ist er 25,70+3,99 Versand. Mit einer Flasche komme ich 41 Jahre aus. Ich bin jetzt 48, dann bin ich 89. Wenn ich 6 Flaschen kaufe, komme ich auf 48+41*6=294. So alt werden nur Leute, die in den USA verurteilt werden. Nix fuer mich. Ausserdem is es gut fuer den Haendler wenn ich direkt ueber ihn bestelle, nicht ueber amazon.

Comment: Ok, I wrote "I" because it makes the question easier to read and it's more generic. Actually I am orderering it, sending it to a friend in Germany without shipping cost and she wants to bring it to me in Austria. Where is the official statement that that is illegal?

Answer (score 3):

You can bring up to 100 ml in a 100 ml bottle as part of your carry on luggage, so your 50 ml is within the limits as long as the bottle is no bigger than 100 ml.
(And you can take as many of those as fit in one bag, which you can seal, of one liter.)
Some airports have the bags available for free, some sell them for more than you pay for a box of bags in a supermarket.
I have at times used a smaller bag if I had only one item and if you only have one small item they may even accept a bigger bag. If you have any bag at home that might work and no time to go to a shop where they sell them, use that bag and replace it at the airport if they have better (size) ones there.
One liter bags are about the size of sandwich bags, in case you do not have a box with the size on.

Freezing is a bad plan for several reasons.
Security has been stopping people bringing frozen liquids onto planes, saying that it was still liquid. (This is not always the case but it has happened.)
The oil may not freeze, as all oils have their own freezing points.
And you can damage the goodness of the oil when you freeze it. Most medical oils have to be kept between given temperatures to stay best.

Traveling between Germany and Austria makes it very unlikely that you will run into trouble with customs, but if you feel the need you can go to the red 'something to declare' exit of the airport and ask.

Comment: Is it likely that those bags are available on the airport (Berlin Tegel)? How much are they? But maybe my friend has a small zip lock bag large enough for the bottle. It just has to be <= 1l.

Answer (score 1):

50ml is within the limits of liquid that you can take in hand luggage on almost any flight.  You will have no problems taking this on board.

The supposed toxicity is unlikely to be a problem. Vitamin D supplements are not prohibited from import or transport, and as you say, many other things are toxic if taken in very large quantities.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was worried because it may be difficult for airport security to be sure the bottle still has the original content and not something dangerous. It would only be possible to taste 1 drop. I've read a mother was made to drink half of the breast milk she brought to make sure it's safe. Also my friend was not allowed to bring neurodermitis cream on a flight.

Comment: You might be asked to drink some. But I wouldn't worry about the alleged toxicity. Vitamin D is safe up to very large doses, and I wouldn't take too seriously the concentration information on the bottle.

Comment: Of course the product could be fake, but I take the specification very seriously. I wouldn't take more than 10 drops (100.000 IU) non repetitively. There are people with hypersensitivity, too.